# How can I sanitize data properly in WordPress plugins?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I am a new WordPress plugin developer. I tried submitting my plugin in WordPress repository, but recieved an error from the review team. The error is like

### Data Must be Sanitized, Escaped, and Validated

When you include POST/GET/REQUEST/FILE calls in your plugin, it's important to sanitize, validate, and escape them. The goal here is to prevent a user from accidentally sending trash data through the system, as well as protecting them from potential security issues. Below are the paths they mentioned:

```
woolive/templates/livecall.php:18: $prodid = $_GET['id'];

    woolive/admin/register.php:201: $prodid = (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : "";

    woolive/admin/settings.php:20: update_option('button_loc_shop_page', $_POST['button_loc_shop_page']);

    woolive/admin/settings.php:28: 
    update_option('button_loc_product_details_page', $_POST['button_loc_product_details_page']);

    woolive/admin/settings.php:30: update_option( 'loginpage_slug', $_POST['loginpage_slug'] );

    woolive/admin/settings.php:31: update_option( 'howtojoinpage_slug', $_POST['howtojoinpage_slug'] );
```

Anyone can share how can I do that? Any comments or directions would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can follow this documentation for sanitizing input fields https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-input

Comment: Hi, I have tried to do that, but couldn't find the way to sanitize it, because here the updat_option is using a POST request as a value. So, not quite sure how can I do that. Can you please share a rough line of code on how can I achieve that? Thanks!!

Comment: You can sanitize before calling update_option according to your field value ex :- `$loginpage_slug= sanitize_text_field( $_POST['loginpage_slug'] );`

Comment: Hi @zillionera_dev, thanks for that code. I tried to use that, but getting this error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'update_option' (T_STRING) in /code/wp-content/plugins/........

Any idea about this?
Thanks..